# Simple c++ calculator -> error: request for member 'compare' in details.std

Tags: c++

I've some experience with java but this is my first time tring to write some c++ code. I've started with a simple calculator but am getting the error "error: request for member 'compare' in details.std". It's probably an easy fix but if you could lend a hand it would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string action();

int main(){
    string details = action();
    string action = "";
    string num1 = "";
    string num2 = "";

    for(int i=0; i<details.length(); i++){
        int pos = 0;
        if(details[i].compare(" ") == 0){
            pos++;
            continue;
        }
        if(pos == 0){
            action += details[i];
        }else if(pos == 1){
            num1 += details[i];
        }else if(pos == 2){
            num2 += details[i];
        }
    }

    if(action.compare("M") == 0){
        cout << stoi(num1)*stoi(num2);
    }else if(action.compare("A") == 0){
        cout << stoi(num1)+stoi(num2);
    }else if(action.compare("S") == 0){
        cout << stoi(num1)-stoi(num2);
    }else if(action.compare("D") == 0){
        cout << stoi(num1)/stoi(num2);
    }

return 0;
}

string action(){
    string returnVal;
    string act;
    string num1;
    string num2;
    cout << "Do you wish to (M)ultiply, (A)dd, (D)ivide or (S)ubtract?\n";
    cin >> act;
    cout << "First Number:\n";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Second Number:\n";
    cin >> num2;
    returnVal = act << " " << num1 << " " << num2;
    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: Most of the `X.compare(Y) == 0` could be simplified to `X == Y`. Because operator overloading is a thing in C++ and quite comfortable.

Comment: As written, you will also compare the whole first word if the user enter **Multiply**. You probably only want to compare the first letter. Also, you probably want to do case insensitive comparison so that user don't need to type uppercase M, A, S or D.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's appreciated. Anyone know why stoi doesn't seem to be working. When i run the code I never get an output. I amn't getting a error message or anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`details` is `string` ([`std::basic_string<char>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)), so `details[i]` is `char`.

`char` doesn't have members. It is one of integer types, so the comparision should be `details[i] == ' '`, not `details[i].compare(" ") == 0`.